# UTFGrid Support or Example for OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3, utfgrids

I realize UTFGrids are not yet supported in OpenLayers 3.

I'm wondering if anyone has created a branch of OL3 that does support UTFGrids, or if there are any examples out there of someone making progress on this front.

Anyone aware of such work?

Comment: The only thing I know of is the ticket at github https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UTFGrid support (including an example) is now part of the OL3 master branch: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3015 (relevant pull request)